# Why does the Next JS and React JS applications take so much cache?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, next.js, server-side-rendering

"What are the factors that contribute to Next.js and React.js applications requiring a significant amount of cache, and how can this impact the performance and resource usage of the applications?"

As a developer I have to refresh all time even we have a small changes in our application. how can I resolve this issue in a easy way.

Answer (score -1):

Above [Next.js 12.3](https://nextjs.org/docs/architecture/fast-refresh#how-it-works), you no longer need to restart your local development server when making changes to those configuration files.

If you using **latest version of Next Js** then try to check below point

- When your parent component mounted as HOC with memo their might be chances of slow down hot reloading process.
- When there is memory leaks

Try to use latest version and make sure you **do n't** configure any specific setting to prevent hot reloading in **next.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  webpack(config) {
    config.plugins = config.plugins.filter(plugin => {
      return plugin.constructor.name !== 'ReactFreshWebpackPlugin';
    });

    return config;
  },
};
```

Comment: Thankyou for reply. But supposed that anyhow we are not able to upgrade our applications so what should do I do . I am using Next JS version of 12.3.4